# Why sort and sorted functions are showing different results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

when I sort this list -> `y = [20, 10 ,20]`

```
y = sorted(y, key = y.count)
# y -> [10, 20, 20]

y.sort(key = y.count)
# y -> [20, 10, 20]
```

why do both functions give different results?

Comment: Just a guess: `y.sort(key = count)` must remove items from the list as part of the sorting process so that `count` returns the wrong result. If you make a copy of `y` (for example: `x = y[:]`) and use `x.count` as the key, you get the correct result: `y.sort(key = x.count)`. I would have to look at the source code for `list.sort` to verify this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `.sort()` method causes the list to appear to be empty while the sort is running, to prevent the key or comparison function from doing stupid things that might result in a crash - so `.count()` is always going to return zero.  `sorted()` doesn't need to do this, because it's not modifying the original list.

Comment: @jason You're exactly right. Check out the link I posted. It references the documentation that says that.